# how to access mapreduce output table in django

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have implemented map reduce and it create a seperate document in mongodb. This is a seperate script which runs daily. now i want to access this table in django application using mongoengine. any idea how can i access this document.

Comment: Have you worked through the tutorial here - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-django-mongo/index.html ?

Comment: Yes i have read this. I m using mongoengine. and i have few documents defined in models.py and every thing is working fine. now i need to access the newly create output document from mapreduce.

Comment: If you are doing an inline map reduce you should have the results in a python variable - which you then can output.

Comment: i m running script which is seperate app. and i want to access the output table from seperate app.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce does not create a document as its output, it creates a new collection.

The name of this collection is specified by you as the "out" parameter when you invoke MapReduce command.

You should now be able to reference db. in your code (or if you are using pyMongo then it would be db["out"] where "out" is the name you specified for the output collection.

For more "out" parameter info see [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/).